# weka clustering with SimpleKMeans confusinig output

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, k-means

I try to run and understand the results of **SimpleKMeans** algorithm in weka.

This is my training data

```
@relation weather_clustered

@attribute Instance_number numeric
@attribute outlook {sunny,overcast,rainy}
@attribute temperature numeric
@attribute humidity numeric
@attribute windy {TRUE,FALSE}
@attribute play {yes,no}
@attribute cluster {cluster0,cluster1,cluster2,cluster3,cluster4,cluster5}

@data
0,sunny,85,85,FALSE,no,cluster3
1,sunny,80,90,TRUE,no,cluster5
2,overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes,cluster2
4,rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes,cluster4
```

Then I run **SimpleKMeans** with **numClusters=2**  **seed=10**. I do want to see clustering results regarding attribute **cluster**, in other words I want to see which cluster attribute **clusterx** relates to. As you see I don't assume that attribute cluster is the right clustering.

In order to see the correspondence in the output, I set 
**Classes to cluster evaluation = (Nom) cluster**

and get the following results

Class attribute: cluster
Classes to Clusters:

```
0 1  <-- assigned to cluster
 0 0 | cluster0
 0 0 | cluster1
 1 0 | cluster2
 0 1 | cluster3
 1 0 | cluster4
 0 1 | cluster5

Cluster 0 <-- cluster2
Cluster 1 <-- cluster3

Incorrectly clustered instances :   2.0  50      %
```

I do like the list with correspondence, this exactly what I need, however I don't understand what's the following means

```
Cluster 0 <-- cluster2
Cluster 1 <-- cluster3
```

In addition, I am confused by the following result

```
Incorrectly clustered instances :   2.0  50      %
```

Where it comes from, how weka knows the correct result, I don't have a correct result, maybe it confuses the attribute cluster with correct cluster. In short I don't understand the output.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleKMeans is a clustering algorithm that groups your data in K clusters.

In your case, having `numClusters=2` => `K=2`, will result in grouping  your data into 2 clusters.

> Cluster 1
>
> Cluster 2

When you selected classes to clusters evaluation, Weka does the following:

1. Removes the attribute values that you selected for evaluation. In your case the **cluster** class data.
2. Applies the KMeans algorithms without using any information from your **cluster** attribute.
3. Evaluates your cluster by using your initial dataset (with your cluster attribute)

So, in your case,

> cluster1, cluster2.., cluster5,

act as labels for your instances and will be used for testing your model.

To better understand the output, you have

```
@data
0,sunny,85,85,FALSE,no,cluster3
1,sunny,80,90,TRUE,no,cluster5
2,overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes,cluster2
4,rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes,cluster4
```

and

```
Cluster 0 <-- cluster2
Cluster 1 <-- cluster3


Incorrectly clustered instances :   2.0  50      %
```

As you can see, there are 2 incorrectly clustered instances:

```
1,sunny,80,90,TRUE,no,cluster5
4,rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes,cluster4
```

And there are 50% incorrectly clusteres instances because you have a total of 4 instances, from which 2 are incorrectly clustered (2 = 50% of 4)